# Conduction Heat transfer through cylinder, the $\ln(r_2/r_1)$ term

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conduction

For steady state, radial conduction heat transfer through a cylinder, all textbooks show a term $\text{ln}(r_2/r_1)$ in the denominator $[q = (2*\pi*k*L*\delta T)/\text{ln}(r_2/r_1)]$, where $r_2>r_1$. There's always an example where heat is transferring from inside the cylinder (1) to the outside (2). However, if heat transfers from (2) to (1) (i.e. higher temperature on the outside surface), does the term remain $\text{ln}(r_2/r_1)$ in the equation, or does it flip to $\text{ln}(r_1/r_2)$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln\frac{r_1}{r_2}=-\ln\frac{r_2}{r_1}$$
So by flipping the arguments of ln, you're merely flipping a sign. You'd do this if $q$ is still defined as the heat flow from inner to outer cylinder.